# creating a plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to plot using `ggplot` but I am a beginner. The data frame (`newdata`) contains 2002 rows and 3 columns. When I use basic graphics `plot` function I get a perfect plot like an inverted bell shape but when I use `ggplot2` I don't get a similar plot. 
(i solved it..my dataframe had character columns,i converted them to numerical values and i plotted it..i works fine now..)
now i have two plots val vs dat1 and val vs dat2 , now i need to combine them using facet wrap...any help would be appreciated..

val = -1000,-999,-998 to 998,999, 1000.
dat1 = 1.2, 3.4, 5.5, 33.3, 55.4, ... 
so on. `dat2` is similar to `y` values.

```
str(newdata)
'data.frame':   2001 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ val  : chr  "-1000" "-999" "-998" "-997" ...
 $ dat1     : num  0.229 0.235 0.247 0.25 0.249 ...
 $ dat2   : num  1.97 1.98 1.98 1.98 1.98 ...

ggplot(data = newdata) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = val, y = dat1))
```

updated..dput(data)
since the data is very huge im adding a part of it.

```
structure(list(**val** = c("-1000", "-999", "-998", "-997", 
"-996", "-995", "-994", "-993", "-992", "-991"), dat1 = c(0.229377104377104, 
0.23526936026936, 0.246843434343434, 0.250210437710438, 0.248526936026936, 
0.252314814814815, 0.226641414141414, 0.230218855218855, 0.223484848484848, 
0.236952861952862),  dat2 = c(1.97385049452862, 
1.97675496296296, 1.97780065909091, 1.97756823063973, 1.97745205218855, 
1.98053092087542, 1.98291262079125, 1.98401634175084, 1.98796655597643, 
1.98639806102694)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please share at least a sample of your data, preferably with either (1) literal code to produce the frame (assuming no underlying CSV or other files required); or (2) the output from `dput(head(newdata))`, with enough data to be able to demonstrate plotting the data. (edit your question and post it there in a code-block, not here in a comment, please!)

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(newdata)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(newdata, 20))`.

Comment: updated dput(data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To facet, you need data in long format (see [this paper](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) for a description of "tidy" data).  Basically, you need one column that holds values of either `dat1` or `dat2`, and another column that distinguishes between rows for `dat1` and rows for `dat2`.

Here's how to accomplish this for your dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Convert from wide to long.  Convert strings to numbers.
data.long = newdata %>%
  gather(dat.type, dat.value, -val) %>%
  mutate(val = as.numeric(val))

# Plot and facet.
ggplot(data.long, aes(x = val, y = dat.value)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ dat.type)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`ggplot(data = newdata, aes(x = val, y = dat1)) + geom_line()`

Comment: (i solved it..my dataframe had character columns,i converted them to numerical values and i plotted it..i works fine now..)